# how to set background color GtkBox in Gtk+3?

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

I create application in GTK+3 and I Would like to change the background color for `GtkBox` but can not here this code:

```
box.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, color);
```

Answer (score 8):

In ["Common Questions"](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-question-index.html#id530878) of GTK+3 is the answer to your question.

In the basic form, you can use:

```
box.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(.5,.5,.5,.5))
```

In this case, the color will be a soft grey, half transparent. Probably, you want to paint it during the `draw` signal.

Comment: I wish they did not deprecated the KISS interface.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid: "gtk_widget_override_background_color has been deprecated since version 3.16 and should not be used in newly-written code."

Comment: @snap Indeed. Thanks for pointing out. With some time, we can update the answer to provide a more comprehensive example. If you need it in a rush, you may want to check https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2016-August/msg00021.html  Also, you are very welcome to update the answer :-)