# GtkWidget, change background color

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Sorry, I'm newbie in the Gtk, so it is may be the stupid question. 
I use Gtk+ 3.0 and have this code

```
GtkWidget *widget;
widget=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 2);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(widget), some_label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

How can I change the background color of the widget? I'm trying that

```
GdkColor red = {0, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x0000};
gtk_widget_modify_bg(widget, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &red);
```

and some other examples, but no one of them worked for my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set background color GtkBox in Gtk+3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166482/how-to-set-background-color-gtkbox-in-gtk3)

Answer (score 4):

In GTK+ 3.0 you can use [`gtk_widget_override_background_color`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-background-color).

Comment: It sounds strange, but this function changed only the font color at the label.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `gtk_widget_override_background_color`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved my problem with GtkCssProvider.

Comment: Great,But it is deprecated now.I hate that

Answer (score 4):

In GTK+3 3.22 this markup code inside the text works.

```
gchar *text = "<b><span font='20' background='#ffffff' foreground='#404040'>I'm a colored label</span></b>";

gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), text);
gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
```